# Create a python virtual enviroment 3.6

Tags: python

I have currently python 3.9.4 in my pc and its interpreter is creating errors due to  version mismatch . I wanted to create a python 3.6 virtual enviroment in my worksapce and use that interpreter in vscode. I know how to create a virtual enviroment but how to create one with 3.6?

Comment: Are you using `virtualenv` or `conda` or what?

Comment: I am using virtualenv

Comment: Do you have python 3.6 installed? If yes, `virtualenv venv --python=<path to python without the brackets> <env name without the brackets>`

Comment: No i don't have python 3.5

Comment: Yea so you need to install it and then do  `virtualenv venv --python=<path to python without the brackets> <env name without the brackets>`